# Disabling the ARP Protocol in Linux Box

Tags: linux, networking

I need to disable the system level ARP protocol to perform some experiment on my Ubuntu 11.10 system.

So please help me in disabling the ARP module/protocol in my system.

Comment: Are you willing to dive into the source code of linux to disable it? ARP is a critical protocol for IPv4 and IPv6. If you disable it you won't be able to use any IP services from your machine

Comment: please clarify what you mean by 'disabling system-level arp'... what do u want not to work, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Using_arptables_to_disable_ARP

Answer (score 13):

To supress ARP on interface `eth0` run the following command as `root`:

> ip link set dev eth0 arp off

To turn it back on again:

> ip link set dev eth0 arp on

Comment: but i want to generate ARP traffic from my program on same interface.

Comment: I know that `ip` is newer and more powerful than `ifconfig` but `ifconfig eth0 -arp`( turning off) and `ifconfig eth0 arp` (turning on) also works.

Answer (score 0):

Disable ARP protocol:

`sudo ifconfig wlan0 -arp`

Enable ARP protocol:

`sudo ifconfig wlan0 arp`